# native memory leak on upgrading jre from 7u45 to 8u144

Tags: java

while upgrading java version from 7u45 to 8u144 we are seeing an increase in the private bytes.
The aplication has a JNI code.
We are using native memory tracker tool but couldn't get much information out of it.
    Below is the detail diff

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=423845KB +45803KB, committed=395637KB +46355KB

-                 Java Heap (reserved=256000KB, committed=256000KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=256000KB, committed=256000KB)

-                     Class (reserved=17012KB +1090KB, committed=16500KB +1218KB)
                            (classes #4676 -22)
                            (malloc=2292KB +1090KB #16585 +7321)
                            (mmap: reserved=14720KB, committed=14208KB +128KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=96081KB +43298KB, committed=96081KB +43298KB)
                            (thread #140 -1)
                            (stack: reserved=44480KB -320KB, committed=44480KB -320KB)
                            (malloc=232KB -2KB #697 -5)
                            (arena=51369KB +43620 #278 -2)

-                      Code (reserved=33771KB +57KB, committed=6083KB +481KB)
                            (malloc=491KB +57KB #1414 +94)
                            (mmap: reserved=33280KB, committed=5592KB +424KB)


[0x6d08528c]
[0x6cf6cd36]
[0x6cf6cf4d]
[0x6cf6d3c7]
                             (malloc=52429KB +43824KB #1639 +1370)
```

as per the above output the increase is in the thread arena which is about 43 MB.
We are trying to use JEMALLOC as well but how to invoke it is hat we are still struggling with. The operating system is windows 7
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above problem is solved in JRE 8 update 152. It was a bug in Hotspot for long running native requests and can be checked in the bug fixes of java 8 update 152 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u152-bugfixes-3850568.html Bug ID: JDK-8164293